# How to partition a 2-D array properly?

Tags: list-manipulation, partitions

Given that I have the following array

```
lst = Array[Subscript[P, #1, #2] &, {5, 5}, {0, 0}]
```

$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 P_{0,0} & P_{0,1} & P_{0,2} & P_{0,3} & P_{0,4} \\
 P_{1,0} & P_{1,1} & P_{1,2} & P_{1,3} & P_{1,4} \\
 P_{2,0} & P_{2,1} & P_{2,2} & P_{2,3} & P_{2,4} \\
 P_{3,0} & P_{3,1} & P_{3,2} & P_{3,3} & P_{3,4} \\
 P_{4,0} & P_{4,1} & P_{4,2} & P_{4,3} & P_{4,4}
\end{array}
\right)$

Then I need to partion it into the following matrix blocks

[image]

[image]

**MY TRIAL**

```
Row[
 {Partition[lst, {2, 3}, {1, 2}] // MatrixForm,
  Partition[lst, {3, 3}, {2, 2}] // MatrixForm,
  Partition[lst, {3, 4}, {2, 3}] // MatrixForm}]
```

[image]

```
Row[
 {Partition[lst, {4, 4}, {3, 3}] // MatrixForm,
  Partition[lst, {5, 5}, {4, 4}] // MatrixForm}]
```

[image]

**ANOTHER TRIAL**

```
Partition[lst, {3, 3}, {2, 2}, 1, {}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
Partition[lst, {4, 4}, {3, 3}, 1, {}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
Partition[lst, {3, 4}, {2, 3}, 1, {}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

I searched the *documentation* of `Partition`, and I didn't discovred a directed method to deal with this problem. Could some know any simple way to do this?I really appreciate it:)

Comment: Case 3: `Partition[lst, {3, 4}, {2, 3}, {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, {}]`.

Comment: For the last two: remember the `Nothing` trick I told you about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also do it layer by layer:

```
Clear[nestPartition]
nestPartition[array_List, nlist_List, dlist_List, klist_List] :=
    Module[{matrix},
      Fold[
        Function[{lst, spec}, 
          lst /. 
            matrix[mt_] :> (
                            matrix[{##}] & @@@ 
                              Partition[
                                mt\[Transpose], 
                                spec[[1]],spec[[2]], spec[[3]], {}]
                           )
        ],
        array // matrix,
        {nlist, dlist, klist}\[Transpose] // Reverse
      ]\[Transpose] /. matrix -> Identity
    ]
```

---

```
MapThread[
        Function[{n, d, k},
            nestPartition[lst, n, d, k] //
                        Map[Grid, #, {-4}] & // Grid[#, Dividers -> Center] & // 
                Column[{n, #}, Frame -> All] &
            ],
        {
                {{2, 3}, {2, 3} - 1, {{1, -1}, {1, -1}}},
                {{3, 3}, {3, 3} - 1, {{1, -1}, {1, -1}}},
                {{3, 4}, {3, 4} - 1, {{1, -1}, {1, 1}}},
                {{4, 4}, {4, 4} - 1, {1, 1}},
                {{5, 5}, {5, 5}, {1, 1}}
                }\[Transpose]
        ] // Row[#, "\t"] &
```

[image: list of partition results]

Comment: Very appreciated! but I need some time to understand your solution:)

Comment: Your post is a new idea for me, I can learn something that I don;t know by that:)

Answer (score 4):

```
partitionBlock[lst_, {a_, b_}] :=
 Module[{row, col, m, n},
  {m, n} = Dimensions[lst, 2];
  row = Mod[m - 1, a - 1];
  col = Mod[n - 1, b - 1];
  Which[
    row == 0 && col == 0,
    Partition[lst, {a, b}, {a - 1, b - 1}],
    row == 0 && col != 0,
    Drop[Partition[lst, {a, b}, {a - 1, b - 1}, 1, {}], -1],
    row != 0 && col == 0,
    Drop[Partition[lst, {a, b}, {a - 1, b - 1}, 1, {}], None, -1],
    row != 0 && col != 0,
    Partition[lst, {a, b}, {a - 1, b - 1}, 1, {}]
   ] /. {} -> Sequence[]
 ]
```

#### TEST

```
lst1 = Array[Subscript[P, #1, #2] &, {5, 5}, {0, 0}];
Map[MatrixForm, partitionBlock[lst1, {2, 3}], {2}]

Map[MatrixForm, partitionBlock[lst1, {3, 3}], {2}]

Map[MatrixForm, partitionBlock[lst1, {3, 4}], {2}]

Map[MatrixForm, partitionBlock[lst1, {4, 4}], {2}]

Map[MatrixForm, partitionBlock[lst1, {5, 5}], {2}]
```

[image]